# corosync and multiple load balancers

Tags: linux, load-balancing, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I am trying to provide HA capabilities for our load balancers (nginx, pgpool and haproxy optionally) using pacemaker/corosync. I have defined three primitives:

1 for the failover IP,

1 for lsb::nginx

1 for lsb::pgpool

and I assume that I can add lsb::haproxy, although I have not tested this scenario.

and grouped them together. My issue is that when for example pgpool goes down, the cluster will switch to the other node, including nginx. From my understanding of the documentation, the failover IP can only be included in one group, making this an all or nothing situation (either all the services work or if one fails, a failover will take place for all three of them). Is it possible to group them together so for example node1 can provide nginx and node2 pgpool and haproxy, using the same virtual IP? Is it even possible? I am using Debian Wheezy with all the packages coming from its repositories (haproxy comes from backports). Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way out is to have 2 fail-over IPs. One for `nginx` and the other for `pgpool + haproxy` pair. That way it will work the way you intend it to. `nginx` can be configured to run from first machine and `pgpool + haproxy` pair from the second one.

Comment: so 3 fail-over IPs for each of the service

Comment: yes, but if you intend to run `pgpool` and `haproxy` from the same node, then you need only 2 failover ips.